# Returning a list of currently running async events

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Is there a system.threading function that would allow me to return whether or not an asynchronous function is still being run?

I want to prevent the user from exiting the application if an asynchronous function is still running (or atleast prompt them before exiting).

I am creating asynchronous functions as tasks and awaiting them in code to prevent the UI from being locked up.

If I could make a simple bool isAsyncRunning I would have the functionality I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Any way? Sure. Keep track of them yourself. That'll work for sure. Your question is too broad. Do some research, try something, if you run into a _specific_ problem, then consider asking a question. Be sure to read [ask], as well as other guidance in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: As posted in the question specifically: I was looking for a threading library implementation, and without keeping track myself.  Thank you for the question recommendations.

Comment: _"I was looking for a threading library implementation"_ -- there are a lot of problems with that goal, not the least being that asynchronous operations are not the same as threads. There are lots of differently implemented asynchronous APIs in .NET, each of which different from the other, using different underlying mechanisms. As .NET has evolved, asynchronous APIs have also become more abstracted; we have e.g. the `Task` object that can map to any number of different asynchronous abstractions. IMO your request is just infeasible, but even if it's possible, you need to constrain the question

Comment: It was my understanding that much like Queue's evolved from Lists, asynchronous methods are very much ingrained in the threading libraries.  This is where my confusion lies - If an async method is sitting in the callstack I would assume there are system libraries to return whether or not one is still waiting to callback to the stack.

Comment: _"asynchronous methods are very much ingrained in the threading libraries" -- your understanding is incorrect. _"If an async method is sitting in the callstack"_ -- not all asynchronous operations are even implemented as a single method. For those that are, those methods do not "sit in the callstack". In fact, the whole point of the modern `async`/`await` feature is that such methods do _not_ remain active; when an asynchronous operation is in progress, an awaiting method returns to the caller. There are other mechanisms that allow the method to resume execution later.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Peter, I will do some research into the differences between threading and async methods.  I think this is my fundamental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what API you are using, but for Tasks you can store them in a synchronized observable collection and remove them when they are completed, then display the collection to the user any time you wish.  You can even wrap them in a tuple of  to store a display name for them, and can allow the user to cancel them if they want.

Comment: Thank you, I am simply creating asynchronous methods and while I am utilizing a queue to store some of the data that is being accessed I was kind of hoping to find a boolean IsAsyncRunning type method?  Would I look through the Threading class for this type of functionality?  Also for the Async functions I am utilizing Task<datastructure> for them.

Comment: Task.TaskStatus should do it.  Though the ultimate solution involves a continuation that updates a wrapper object containing your task's name, the task itself, and its status when it is complete, and that wrapper will implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that it can tell a UI when the task changes.  The continuation would also need to remove the task from the synchronized list of running tasks.

Comment: Hoodaticus, just to clarify, as I still am trying to understand how Async methods are not "related" to threading (I feel like it would need to be atleast behind the scenes)...  Is this just as applicable to my public async Task<bool> somethingRunning() methods?  I'm about to give it a try but any clarification would be great.

Comment: Yes, it's applicable to all tasks.  Add them to a ConcurrentBag<Tuple<Task, string>>, and add a ContinuesWith to them before you run them that removes them from the bag.  You can then poll the bag occasionally while displaying a screen to update it, or you can roll some custom concurrent observable collection to handle it better.